# How to change position of `musicography` characters?

Tags: pdftex, music

I want to display some musical notes inside normal text in a latex document.
This is the piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{musicography}

\begin{document}

Simple time signatures, such as $2/4$ or $3/4$, signify a binary beat subdivision (\eg{} in $3/4$ the beat is given by the quarter note, which is divisible in 2 eighth notes \musQuarter = \musEighth + \musEighth)

%\musQuarterDotted = \musEighth + \musEighth + \musEighth 

\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

How can I put the "=" more centred between the quarter note and the sixteenth note, and the "+" also equally centred between both sixteenth notes?

Note: I have to use `musicography`as I'm using `pdflatex` and can not change this (for instance for `xelatex`, in which case I could opt by the `liliglpyh` package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX is gobbling the spaces after those commands. Instead write `\musQuarter{} = \musEighth{} + \musEighth{}`.